# How to use the border-radius property to create a button like this?

Tags: css

Can I use the `border-radius` property to style a button to look like this?

[image: button example]

Comment: You should be able to see the property when inspecting the button, my guess is `50% 0`

Comment: this is a image design so I can't inspect it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Answer (score 3):

Another Style method

`border-top-left-radius: 30px; border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;`

```css
.btn
{
background-color:red;
border-radius:30px 0 30px 0;
padding:10px 30px;
color:#fff;
font-size:17px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
```

You can play around with that like you want

Answer (score -1):

Try this it will be better

```css
.btn
{
background-color:red;
border-radius:30px 5px;  
padding:10px 30px;
color:#fff;
font-size:17px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Text</button>
```